# Routing on NodeJS for Serverside-rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm setting up a nodejs server capable of doing serverside rendering for a reactjs app.
Currently I'm struggling with certain types of routes. i.e. Routes with longer pathnames.

I tried setting up the nodejs server in different ways. Changed the order of the middlewares. Currently I removed all Routes from the SSR process and it is still not working.

```
// NodeJs Server.js
import '@babel/polyfill';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { ssrMiddleware, csrMiddleware } from './Middlewares';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(ssrMiddleware);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(csrMiddleware);
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

```
// CSR Middleware
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import webConfig from '../../../webConfig';

const routerCSR = express.Router();

routerCSR.get(['*/:param', '*'], (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req, "csr request");
  const indexFile = path.resolve(webConfig.html.path, 'index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Errorpage CSR 500er');
    }

    return res.status(200).send(data);
  });
});

export default routerCSR;
```

```
// SSR Middleware
import { SSRPaths } from 'Router/routes';
import { ssrRouter } from '../Router';

const ssrMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { path } = req;
  console.log('SSR', SSRPaths.includes(path), '\n with path: ', path);
  if (SSRPaths.includes(path)) return ssrRouter(req, res, next);
  return next();
};

export default ssrMiddleware;
```

```
// CSR Router
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import webConfig from '../../../webConfig';

const routerCSR = express.Router();

routerCSR.get(['*/:param', '*'], (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req, "csr request");
  const indexFile = path.resolve(webConfig.html.path, 'index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Errorpage CSR 500er');
    }

    return res.status(200).send(data);
  });
});

export default routerCSR;
```

```
// SSR Router
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import { StoreManager } from 'Storage/redux';
import messages from 'Translations/languages';
import AppWrapper from 'AppWrapper';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import history from 'Router/history';
import App from '../../App';
import webConfig from '../../../webConfig';

const routerSSR = express.Router();

routerSSR.get(['*/:param', '*'], (req, res) => {
  const URL_Param = req.params.param || null; // eslint-disable-line
  const context = {
    URL_Param,
  };
  const routerConfig = { location: req.url, context, history };
  const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <AppWrapper {... {
      StoreManager,
      Router: StaticRouter,
      routerConfig,
      messages,
      isSSR: true,
    }}
    >
      <App />
    </AppWrapper>,
  );
  const indexFile = path.resolve(webConfig.html.path, 'index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Errorpage SSR 500er');
    }
    const preloadedState = StoreManager.store.getState();
    return res
      .status(200)
      .send(
        data
          .replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${content}</div>`)
          .replace('window.__PRELOADED_STATE__=false', `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
            /</g,
            '\\u003c',
          )}`),
      );
  });
});

export default routerSSR;
```

```
// SSRPaths
import Contact from 'Pages/Contact';
import DataPolicy from 'Pages/DataPolicy';
import Imprint from 'Pages/Imprint';
import Landing from 'Pages/Landing';
import SearchResult from 'Pages/SearchResult';


const Routes = {
  Contact: {
    exact: true,
    path: '/contact',
    component: Contact,
  },
  DataPolicy: {
    exact: true,
    path: '/data-policy',
    component: DataPolicy,
  },
  Imprint: {
    exact: true,
    path: '/imprint',
    component: Imprint,
  },
  Landing: {
    exact: true,
    path: '/',
    component: Landing,
  },
  LocationDetails: {
    exact: false,
    path: '/location/:id',
    component: LocationDetails,
  },
};

const ssrRoutesByName = [
  // 'Contact',
  // 'Imprint',
  // 'DataPolicy',
];

export const SSRRoutes = (() => {
  const res = {};
  ssrRoutesByName.forEach((name) => {
    res[name] = Routes[name];
  });
  return res;
})();

export const SSRPaths = (() => {
  const paths = [];
  Object.keys(SSRRoutes).map(key => SSRRoutes[key]).forEach((routeObj) => {
    if (routeObj.path) paths.push(routeObj.path);
  });
  return paths;
})();

export default Routes;
```

1) Routes with Paths of order 1 are working fine, e.g. MyDomain.com/contact

2) Routes with Paths of order 2 or bigger are not working, e.g. MyDomain.com/location/123

I expected the Server to return a normal index.html and the clientside routing to handle the route,
but the NodeJs Server does return a html file but names it as the last piece of the pathname in the route.

For example 2) it would name it 123.html and throw some parsing error on client side in the browser. (see screenshot)

URL:
http://localhost:3000/location/11

Here you can see the response and other screenshots to clarify

**Html file client receives**
[image: Html file client receives]

**Clientside Error**
[image: Clientside Error]

**Headers**
[image: Response Type]

Comment: Could you check the content-type of the request? Make sure that it is text/html (looking at the error that does not recognize < it might expect json?).

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer.
As you can see in the screenshot of the chrome dev tool, the content-type of the response certainly is text/html.

Comment: By now I have found out, that one main problem is, that depending on the path I try to access, e.g. myUrl.com/locations/id 
my browser tries to access the assets via the same path:
myUrl.com/locations/style.css
myUrl.com/locations/bundle.js
etc.

Comment: I also see that the amount of data on all files that are received is exactly the same (945b). That cannot be right.

Comment: You are right. I actually partially fixed the problem. It was due to Webpack HtmlPlugin which was wrongly configured and injected relative paths to the header of the html for css, js, etc. Thats why the express middleware for static files was skipped ( for route: url.com/location/id it tried url.com/location/bundle.js )

Therefore my CSR middleware returned index.html instead.
crazy. But thanks for your help! 

I will try to update or fix the rest and update afterwards